# Disable a radio button if previous value is false in while loop PHP

Tags: php

[image]i'm sorry if my english is not perfect but i will explain the situation with my best, basically my goal is to disable/hide the radio button if the previous loop value of status is pending, below is my code

```
$allPaid = true
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2Q))
{
    $bill = $row2['billPay_id'];
    $amount = $row2['billPay_amount'];
    $interest = $row2['billPay_interest'];
    $payAmount = $row2['billPay_amountPaid'];
    $payInterest = $row2['billPay_interestPaid'];
    $makeUp = $row2['billPay_makeUp'];
    $billStatus = $row2['billPay_status'];

    $date = $row2['billPay_collectOn'];
    $date = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($date));
    $PayDate = $row2['billPay_payOn'];
    if($PayDate == "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
    {
        $PayDate = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $PayDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($PayDate));
    }

    if($billStatus == 0)
    {
        $status = "Pending";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "Paid";
    }

    echo "
            <tr>
                <form>
                    <td>$no</td>
                    <td>$date</td>
                    <td>$PayDate</td>
                    <td>$amount</td>
                    <td>$payAmount</td>
                    <td>$payInterest</td>
                    <td>$makeUp</td>
                    <td>$status</td>
        ";

    if(($status == "Pending")&&($allPaid == true))
    {

        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='colDate' value='$date' onclick='payData()'></input></td>";
        $allPaid = false;

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td></td>";
        $allPaid = true;
    }

    echo "      </form>
            </tr> ";

    $date = date("y-m-d",strtotime($date));
    $no++;
}
```

what i am doing right now is making a payment system where customer need to pay the bill before able to pay the next bill, so before paying the current bill the next bill radio button will not appear or hidden, in this system the radio button is act as selector,is there any way to achieved that? any help will be very helpful, thank you

UPDATED
i have update the code based on Anggara suggestion, but the output is a little bit off [image: result after updating the code based on anggara suggestion]

Answer (score 0):

If your page showing only one bill for one person, you can add a variable indicating the person has paid all previous bills.

```
$allPaid = true; // declare here

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2Q))
{
    $bill = $row2['billPay_id'];
    $amount = $row2['billPay_amount'];
    $interest = $row2['billPay_interest'];
    $payAmount = $row2['billPay_amountPaid'];
    $payInterest = $row2['billPay_interestPaid'];
    $makeUp = $row2['billPay_makeUp'];
    $billStatus = $row2['billPay_status'];

    $date = $row2['billPay_collectOn'];
    $date = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($date));
    $PayDate = $row2['billPay_payOn'];
    if($PayDate == "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
    {
        $PayDate = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $PayDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($PayDate));
    }

    if($billStatus == 0)
    {
        $status = "Pending";
        $allPaid = false; // there is a bill unpaid
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "Paid";
    }

    echo "
            <tr>
                <form>
                    <td>$no</td>
                    <td>$date</td>
                    <td>$PayDate</td>
                    <td>$amount</td>
                    <td>$payAmount</td>
                    <td>$payInterest</td>
                    <td>$makeUp</td>
                    <td>$status</td>
        ";

    if($status == "Pending" && $allPaid) // show only if previous bills are paid
    {

        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='colDate' value='$date' onclick='payData()'></input></td>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }

    echo "      </form>
            </tr> ";

    $date = date("y-m-d",strtotime($date));
    $no++;
}
```

Comment: if we go to the picture above, there is 4 rows which is consist of 2 bills has been paid and 2 bill unpaid, the paid bill is correct where no radio button shown, then we go to the pending bill, the problem is the second pending bill, my aim is to disable the second pending bill radio button when the first pending bill is still unpaid and it will only show when the first pending bill is paid

Comment: If your page showing bills only for one person, you can add a variable indicating the person has paid all previous bills. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: i have implemented your suggestion, and it only work for the second row of unpaid bill. the radio button will show out again on the third bill

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly, this should do what you want

replace

```
if($status == "Pending")
{

    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='colDate' value='$date' onclick='payData()'></input></td>";

}
else
{
    echo "<td></td>";
}
```

with

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='colDate' value='$date' onclick='payData()' ". (($status == 'Pending')? 'disabled':'') ."></input></td>";
```

if you want to hide it you can replace disabled with hidden

Comment: thank you for answering my question, what i am aiming is when the previous row bill status is paid then the next bill radio button is usable, but if the previous row bill status is pending then the next bill radio button will be hidden or disabled